What 1970s microcomputers supported ≥ 512 pixels/line NTSC output?
What pre-1980 microcomputers, either internally or via an expansion card, supported NTSC-frequency (or similar) video output with a pixel clock giving at least 512 pixels per line?
Note that I'm not asking about having bitmap (or other) graphics support at this resolution; text display at this resolution is fine.
Please include the release date and any other details you now about the output format, such as output signalling (TTL, composite sync, etc.), colour support, and so on.
The first example would be the NEC PC-8001, which output 640×200 in eight colours on a TTL RGB output (R, G, B, hsync, vsync) and in eight levels of intensity on a CVBS output (NTSC black and white: combined intensity, negative hsync and negative vsync with no colour burst), used to generate text displays of up to 80 columns by 25 lines from a 256 glyph character set. (Third parties soon made a programmable character set generator that allowed reprogramming the character set on the fly.)

Isn't this asking straight for (a) list answer(s)?

Also, it seems a bit wide, as I would think each and every 80 column, pixel based text-terminal does qualify to above wording, especially by not requiring bit map. Which, by the second half of the 1970, were almost entirely micro based. If not on their own, connecting to a micro (think Altair) will solve that requirement, wouldn't it?

If anyone else feels, as Raffzahn does, that "microcomputers" includes "terminals," please feel free to edit the question to make it clear that it doesn't. (I personally don't think of a VT100 as very distinct from a "microcomputer," but perhaps I'm odd in this.)

The Commodore PET 8000 series (80 column 640x200) just misses the window first being released in May of 1980. There may have been 80-column expansion boards for the earlier pets that released sooner, but I don't have any solid evidence. There are a number of known upgrade boards but it's hard to pin down release dates for some of them.

@cjs Please tone down and don't twist my words - while at the same time avoiding the issue. The question is in many ways unclear and weak defined - like titling with NTSC, which is a standard for modulating a colour signal for TV on top of VBS B&W signal - which BTW is by back then standard in not capable of doing >512 pixel anyway. Also asking for a list.

@Raffzahn You may remember NTSC as a standard for colour modulation, but it existed long before that as a monochrome standard, and that monochrome standard was used frequently into the microcomputer age. Consider, e.g., that the Apple II had explicit circuitry and code to use NTSC monochrome, instead of NTSC colour, when monochrome would make text look better. ¶ And NTSC (in monochrome) is perfectly capable of doing at least 640 pixel horizontal resolution: I personally own several machines that do this, and display this quite clearly on monochrome (and even some colour) monitors.

@Raffzahn You do realise that you can just submit a close vote on questions you don't like, right? So why do you instead start a flamewar in the comments? (That's a rhetorical question; please don't answer. Just think about it to yourself.)

cjs, Raffzahn is using comments as they are intended to be used. Silent close votes are actually discouraged (except for blatant duplicates, where a comment is automatically generated). @Raffzahn, please be quicker to take things to [meta], so we can establish consensus rather than having the same discussions over and over in the comments; and do try to confirm before asserting that other people have made factual errors. (Also, list questions are not always forbidden on Stack Exchange sites: some even have dedicated tags for them. Again, if you disagree, we need to find a consensus on [meta].)

@Raffzahn cjs is right - The first TV standard by the NTSC in the 40s was the monochrome one that became EIA RS-170. The next standard by the NTSC in the 50s included color, leading to RS-170A.

It's possibly worth noting that this is why 640 pixels/line NTSC-frequency machines such as the PC-8001 and FM-7 supported colour only via RGB and generated a black-and-white signal on the CVBS output. (NTSC colour doesn't support 640 pixels across; NTSC black and white does just fine, and many black-and-white TVs will even display it with reasonable quality, as well most monochrome monitors.)

@wizzwizz4 Yes, after some thought, I agree with you. I guess my issue is that Raffzahn frequently makes comments like the above "Isn't this asking straight for (a) list answer(s)?" which don't really seem to lead toward any reasonable conversation about whether and what kind of "list answers" are ok, but just passively-aggressively encode an assumption that questions inviting list answers are (or ought to be) verboten, which leads me to ask "why not just vote to close, then?"

The Acord System supported it, but the 80 column card might have been after 1980.
The arcade game Sprint had a display of 512x224 iirc and all the Atari vector games have a grid of I think 1024x768 for the start and end point of each line.

@RichardBroadhurst I'm looking for microcomputers, under which definition I don't consider arcade games to fall.

The ECD MicroMind used a voltage controlled oscillator as a pixel clock, Pixels/line was variable up to >600 (depending on the individual machine). It had NTSC composite video output. With a good monochrome monitor, 80 columns at 7 pixel pitch (5 by 7 font) was usable, although "m" was just a smudge. That's 560 pixels per line.
The basic limitation wasn't the computer hardware, but the monitors available for a reasonable price. NTSC luminance bandwidth is 4.2 MHz, but more is needed to resolve >450 pixels per line. Affordable monitors were based on consumer television technology and lacked extra bandwidth.
Only about 50 were made, in 1977/78.

NTSC luminance bandwidth is limited to 4.2 MHz or so in broadband transmission, but there's no particular limit for baseband. I don't know that I've ever seen a monochrome CVBS computer monitor that had any issue with clearly resolving, e.g., the 640 pixels put out by my FM-7 or various other machines. Even kinda crappy old "security" monitors seem to do just fine with it. All are invariably better than any colour monitor I own.

@cjs Consumer video monitors were rare and not very good in 1977. Industrial monitors were better, but rather spendy for a microcomputer.

Yeah, I'm just not buying this. I am not disagreeing that consumer monochrome displays (of any kind, monitor or TV) were designed to display a 4.5 MHz signal, which would generally mean no more than 3 dB down at 4.5 MHz. But they're not likely to have a very steep rolloff on that since there's no reason to spend extra time and money to filter it; the rolloff will just be whatever's "natural" to the system, slightly reducing the quality of edges on e.g. a 640 pixel signal, but hardly destroying them. It's colour that causes all the resolution problems.

@cjs All I remember from 45 years ago is lots of smudgy "m" characters. I have some examples of WYSIWYG output from a dot matrix plotter, and I was using 80 columns at a 7 pixel pitch (the plotter had no trouble with this). I don't think I commonly used higher resolution.

@cjs  Are your monitors from the 70's? Bandwidth was expensive back then: fast transistors capable of driving a grid hard weren't common. There wasn't much demand for high bandwidth, so there wasn't much production. I remember going to a trade show and wishing we could afford the better monitors I saw there, but one of those cost as much as the computer. A decade later, NeXT's "megapixel" high-res monitor was a big deal.


Ohio Scientific Challenger IIP (1977) 64x32 text w/8x8 font, UHF RF
Exidy Sorcerer (1978-06) 64x30 text w/8x8 font, 512x240 bitmap, composite
Ohio Scientific C4P (1979) 64x32 text w/8x8 font, 512x256 bitmap


Can you please include the actual horizontal pixel resolution of those first three entries? I think you may find that at least one of them is not actually generating 512 or more horizontal pixels.

Yep, I use my hand-made 7 pixel wide font that works great on a CRT and that would be less than 512 pixels with 64 characters.

@pipe doesn't a 7 pixel wide font normally have a one pixel margin on the side? That would make the Sol-20 (only just) qualify

@OmarandLorraine With monospace bitmap fonts you stack them together, just like 8 pixel wide fonts are aligned to bytes etc. If you need margins for your letters (which you typically do) you have to include them in the 7 pixels.

@pipe: It's pretty common for bitmap hardware to only have provisions for as many pixels as can be non-blank; an IBM monochrome display adapter, for example, has nine dot clocks per character but uses an 8-bit shift register (some character codes will latch the last bit rather than clocking in an empty one, so as to allow line-drawing characters to connect, but that's a function of dedicated hardware rather than being part of the font).

@pipe - that takes me back to 1981 when I managed to write, using a library book as guidance,  a 6502 assembly routine to show 64 characters per line on an Acorn Atom's 256x192 graphics screen.  A hand made 4-pixel-wide font held in DATA statements. 3 pixels per char plus a 1 pixel side margin.

To be clear, I'm looking for the actual number of output pixels, regardless of how generated, so 80 characters of 7 pixels with a dark pixel inserted between each character by the hardware would be 640 pixel output, not 560 pixel output.
